# suggestion for admin

Tags: discussion, support

There should be a way the person who asks the question can send $10 by Paypal to the person who answers the question without disclosing email. The site has the email, so just enable a button to send the equivalent of a six pack. Also, users who express such gratitude should be marked, so people who can answer questions will know they can get sth by answering the question.

Comment: If you liked the help that much, ask the person that helped you if they'd be willing to accept something like that, and then just coordinate with them to get a pay link if they have paypal and they can provide you a way to sending money to their account if they'd accept something like that. Be sure to stay around, gain more rep, use more often for both questions and answers, and that too will be you paying it forward helping the next person out just like you got help. There are many SE communities and SU is just one so keep using and playing and paying it forward like that too.

Comment: The day somebody can pay me or anyone for help is the day, I delete every single one of my answers, and delete my account.  If I wanted to be paid for my help, I would have taken steps, to do exactly that years ago

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT - There is no mechanism to allow for private help.  I always report people who offer private help to a moderator.

Comment: @Ramhound The reason I mentioned this is because I've seen profiles of long time users that say donations are welcomed in a sense but not word for word.... https://superuser.com/users/30792/spiff. In this case it's crypto coin currency but monetary donations or tips are just that. I wouldn't blame you for doing that but it seems this is already occurring. I didn't say I agree with it, but I haven't seen any rules that says it's prohibited.

Comment: You mean I could have received tips all this time?  I am kidding, it’s disgusting that is allowed, as long as answer are never behind a pay wall like Quora it will be fine.  I hate Quora by the way.  They make you create an account, which they end up leaking, in order to see the comments submitted as answers.

Answer (score 4):

As someone with lots of reputation and experience... This won't happen.

The purpose of the site is to ask people for *free* help, not to come here and *expect* to be compensated for their efforts.

It's great if you found an answer that was extra-helpful, or that you're willing to pay, but the way we say "Thanks" here is with upvotes, choosing the answer as the best, or bounties.